# Unable to get Serial.print to work

Tags: arduino

I have a simple program:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int x = 0;
  Serial.print(x++);
}
```

Whenever I try to look and see the serial log nothing is shown, what am I doing wrong. I am using a Arduino Leonardo and the sketch compiles and uploads.

-----------------Update 1---------------

What I am really trying to get the console to print out is the following code. However since it failed I made a short and simple program:

```
// SparkFun Soil Moisture Sensor and Serial LCD example 1
// By Sarah Al-Mutlaq 2015
// Sketch reads sensor and desplays level and whether soil is wet or dry

// Use the softwareserial library to create a new "soft" serial port
// for the display. This prevents display corruption when uploading code.
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

// Attach the serial display's RX line to digital pin 2
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3,2); // pin 2 = TX, pin 3 = RX (unused)


// Here we are setting up some water thersholds that we will 
// use later. Note that you will need to change these to match
// your soil type and environment. 

int thresholdUp = 400;
int thresholdDown = 250;

// We are setting up the pin A0 on the redboard to be our sensor
// pin input:

int sensorPin = A0;


void setup(){
  mySerial.begin(9600); // set up serial port for 9600 baud (speed)
  delay(500); // wait for display to boot up
}

void loop(){
  // Here we are declaring a string, which are lines of words,
  // and we want DisplayWords to be the words displayed on
  // the LCD screen, which will change based on whether the soil
  // wet or dry based on our threshold values above.
  String DisplayWords;

  // We need to set up a pin to get the value that the soil 
  // moisture sensor is outputting, so sensorValue will get the
  // analog value from the sensor pin A0 on the redboard that we 
  // set up earlier.

  int sensorValue;
  sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);

  // move cursor to beginning of first line on LCD:
  mySerial.write(254); 
  mySerial.write(128);

  // clear display:
  mySerial.write("                "); 
  mySerial.write("                ");

  // move cursor to beginning of first line of the LCD screen:
  mySerial.write(254); 
  mySerial.write(128);

  //Write what we want to desplay on the screen:
  mySerial.write("Water Level: ");
  mySerial.print(sensorValue); //Using .print instead of .write for values

  // Now we are going to check if the water level is below a 
  // out thresholdDown value we set earlier, and if it is have 
  // words "Dry, Water it!" display one column over on the first 
  // row:

  if (sensorValue <= thresholdDown){
    // move cursor to beginning of second line on LCD:
    mySerial.write(254); 
    mySerial.write(192);

    DisplayWords = "Dry, Water it!";
    mySerial.print(DisplayWords);

  // If the value is not below our thresholdDown value we want to 
  // check if it is above our thresholdUp value, and if it is 
  // change the display words to "Wet, Leave it!":



  } else if (sensorValue >= thresholdUp){
    // move cursor to beginning of second line on LCD:
    mySerial.write(254); 
    mySerial.write(192);

    DisplayWords = "Wet, Leave it!";
    mySerial.print(DisplayWords);

  // Otherwise if it is inbetween the two values we want it to 
  // the display it had, so if our soil was really wet and drying 
  // the words would only change to "Dry, Water it!" when it got to the lower threshold
  // (thresholdDown), but if it was dry and getting wetter the words
  // would only change to "Wet, Leave it!" when it got to the upper 
  // threshold (thresholdUp_):

  } else {
    // move cursor to beginning of second line on LCD:
    mySerial.write(254); 
    mySerial.write(192);

    mySerial.print(DisplayWords);
  }

  delay(500); //wait for half a second, so it is easier to read
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see now you're controlling a display.  Using these isn't like sending bytes to a terminal emulator.  They must be controlled.  Controlling these serial displays generally consists of sending some initialization commands, which are often (but not always) similar for different displays, provided they have the same display controller.

I don't know what display part you're using, but I'd venture that some initialization commands are missing.  The 500ms delay is usually part of it, but check your documentation for any other init commands you need to send before sending cursor positioning commands.

Usually you have to send an initial byte command to put the display into command mode, send a handful of configuration commands, then exit command mode to actually use the display.  If it's a Hitachi 44780 based display you might check out the datasheet at [44780 datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf).

Comment: @Drew1208  changed my answer completely based on seeing your doing LCD control.